# Wrong data writing to List (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have repository where I do calculations

Here is code of repository :

```
 public List<HeatmapViewModel> GetStops()
    {
        using (var ctx = new GoogleMapTutorialEntities())
        {
            List<HeatmapViewModel> items = new List<HeatmapViewModel>();

            #region firstitem_calculation
            var firstitem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 1).AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new Logging
                 {
                     Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                     Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                     CurDateTime = x.CurDateTime

                 }).FirstOrDefault();

             var midnight = new DateTime(firstitem.CurDateTime.Year, firstitem.CurDateTime.Month, firstitem.CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
             TimeSpan difference = (firstitem.CurDateTime - midnight);
             var difference_after_midnight = (int) difference.TotalMinutes;
             

             items.Add( new HeatmapViewModel
                 {   Latitude2 = firstitem.Latitude2,
                     Longitude2 = firstitem.Longitude2,
                     FirstStartDifference = difference_after_midnight
                 });
            #endregion

            #region lastitem_calculation
            var lastItem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
                 x => new Logging
                 {
                     Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                     Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                     CurDateTime = x.CurDateTime

                 }).LastOrDefault();
            var before_midnight = new DateTime(lastItem.CurDateTime.Year, lastItem.CurDateTime.Month, lastItem.CurDateTime.Day, 23, 59, 00);
            TimeSpan difference_before = (before_midnight - lastItem.CurDateTime);
            var difference_before_midnight = (int)difference_before.TotalMinutes;

            items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel
            {
                Latitude2 = firstitem.Latitude2,
                Longitude2 = firstitem.Longitude2,
                LastStartDifference = difference_after_midnight
            });

            #endregion
            
           return items;
         }
        

    }
```

And then I call method in Controller

Here is code of controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetStops()
    {
        var stops = repo.GetStops();

        return Json(stops.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

But on breakpoint on this line `return Json(stops.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

I have 2 elements in array, but it's same data.

First array object
[image: FIrst]

Second array object
[image]

Where is my trouble?

Thank's so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the first item instead of the second item in the second add to the items list:

```
items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel
        {
            Latitude2 = firstitem.Latitude2,
            Longitude2 = firstitem.Longitude2,
            LastStartDifference = difference_after_midnight
        });
```

Comment: Oh, I don't see that. Thank's